# Best datatype for a memdump of a specific address

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm writing a memdump application in C and the goal is to print a real piece of the application memory of a specific address. The code I already have is this:

```
void memdump(byte_t *ptr, long size ) {
```

...

```
  typedef unsigned char byte_t;
  byte_t data[size];
  //&data[0] = &ptr;
  byte_t * pointer_to_byte = data;


  for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j+=10) {
    printf("%p ",&data[j]);
    for (size_t i = j; i < j+10; i++) {
      printf("%02x ",*(pointer_to_byte+i));
    }
    for (size_t i = j; i < j+10; i++) {
      if (isprint(*(pointer_to_byte+i))) {
        printf("%c",*(pointer_to_byte+i));
      } else {
        printf("." );
      }
    }
      printf("\n" );
    }
}
```

main.c:

```
    void  *start_addr;
...
    scanf("%p", &start_addr);
...
    memdump( (byte_t*)start_addr, size );
```

You can see that I use an array to obtain the memory block, but this might not be the best way. Now I would like to get the address as a parameter to scan and my question is what is the best datatype to get this address and any idea's how I can change my code up so I can use the specific address? I already use a pointer to print the data and the char, so a pointer is the best way I think.

Comment: `[help-me]` Please write an MCVE. How do you declare `ptr`? Hint: `&data[0] = &ptr;` does not do what you hope it does.

Comment: No I already found out that &data[0] = &ptr; was not the way. and yes, I'm a way to chaotic personn I will edit the question.

Comment: What is the point of `data`? Delete it and see where it gets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
void memdump(byte_t *ptr, long size ) {
  byte_t * baseptr; /* base addr for each row */
  for (size_t j = 0; j < size; j+=10) { /* row loop */
    baseptr = ptr+j;
    printf("%p ",baseptr);
    for (size_t i = j; i < j+10; i++) { /* hex code */
      printf("%02x ",*(baseptr+i));
    };
    for (size_t i = j; i < j+10; i++) { /* char print */
      if (isprint(*(baseptr+i))) {
        printf("%c",*(baseptr+i));
      } else {
        printf(".");
      };
    };
    printf("\n" );
  };
};
```

Comment: If size isn't a multiple of 10, you'll access outside the size on the laster iteration of the row loop.

Comment: yes, it will just continu till the next multiple of 10.

Answer (score 0):

`void const *` is the best datatype for `ptr`; everything else will require casts.  `size` should be of type `size_t` too:

```
void memdump(void const *ptr, size_t size ) {
    uint8_t const *data = ptr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        ...
```